# Return custom type x composed of custom type y in atomic table format PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I have a custom type:

```
CREATE TYPE single_journey AS (
tram_id integer, 
departure_station text,
departure_time time,
destination_station text,
arrival_time time);
```

and another custom type:

```
CREATE TYPE double_journey AS (
    journey_one single_journey, 
    journey_two single_journey);
```

The second custom type exists because I have a function that can return two single_journey types together.

The problem is, the output is like this:

```
journey_one                               journey_two
single_journey                            single_journey
----------------------------------------  ----------------------------------------
(39,StationX,11:00:00,StationY,12:00:00)  (40,StationY,12:30:00,StationZ,13:00:00
```

What I desire is each column of each single_journey in double_journey to be in it's own separate column. Is this possible or would I have to re-create the double_journey type with the columns I want e.g. departure_station_1, departure_time_1...arrival_station_2, arrival_time_2 etc...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
 SELECT journey_one, journey_two
```

USE

```
 SELECT journey_one, 
        (journey_two).field1,
        (journey_two).field2,
        (journey_two).field3, etc
```